# Is the 'Product Code' supposed to be unique?

Tags: product

trying to setup our products as a SaaS vendor/provider.

Is the product's field `Product Code` supposed to uniquely identify the product or is it more of a code representing the `Product Family`?

Do you have any advice how to properly use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the Product Code field isn't unique. As it states [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=products_fields.htm&language=en_US), it's purpose is:

> The internal code or product number that you use to identify the product.

However, it is possible to make it unique, kinda. There's a discussion about this [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gotSAAQ). The take aways from this is to "de-duplicate" either by:

- An app called DupeCatcher
- A Trigger
- A bit of a hacky way involving creating new fields

There's a bit more of an in-depth explanation as to the use of Product Families in Salesforce which you can read about [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_productfamily.htm&language=en_US). But to steal a bit from that resource:

> Use the Product Family picklist to categorize your products. For example, if your company sells both hardware and software, you can create two product families: Hardware and Software.

So I guess the simple answer to your questions:

> Is the 'Product Code' supposed to be unique?

No.

> ... is it more of a code representing the Product Family?

If you want it to be.

How you use the Product object is really up to you and will differ between businesses. I'd say that if your concern is that you want Products to be uniquely identifiable (which, judging from your question it is), I'd use a Trigger that prevented duplicate Product Codes but again, this is just what I'd do.

Comment: OOB Duplicate Management seems like it should be the *first* choice.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - OOB Duplicate Management doesn't work for `Product2` - or, for that matter, [any standard object other than Account - Lead - Contact](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_considerations.htm&type=5). sad.

Comment: @crop wow that's crazy. I wouldn't have thought that to be the case.